# Hand tools for cutting glued boards to size?

Tags: woodworking, furniture

I'm a complete novice to woodworking - I have a few plans in mind (tables and such like) that involve gluing boards to make tops, sides and so forth.

My idea is to glue boards to make panels larger than I actually need them to be and then shape them to size afterwards... but I don't have a table saw, nor anywhere to put one should I buy one (without commandeering the dining room).

So my question is - what's the best combination of hand (power) tools to achieve this? I have a plunge router, so I was thinking of grabbing a circular saw, using that to trim the panels to roughly the right size and then using the router with a fence to square everything off.

What other options do I have?

Comment: This would probably get better answers on [Woodworking SE](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I;ve used the rough cut then router many times. works great.

Answer (score 0):

A hand plane [like this](http://www.factoryauthorizedoutlet.com/dewalt-3-1-4-inch-portable-electric-hand-planer?google=1&CAWELAID=829717549&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=19732019651&CATCI=pla-107150403731&gclid=CJ7Lgdyn8M4CFU9ffgodLkoD5w) can be used to shave the boards down to size. They can be used with over sized rough hard or soft wood. I used mine to make some 2' wide x 4' long 3" thick to make some nice end tables out of rough walnut. I have also made tapered legs by starting several cuts 6" down on all 4 sides then several more , Once all the steps are cut several full length passes on all 4 sides Makes a nice square tapered leg. 
Planes are not a multipurpose tool like some others but can help create very nice hand crafted work.